# Issues with launching and running Deep3DFace_Recon_pytorch

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to work with Deep3DFace_Recon_pytorch. When trying to obtain face landmarks by running the face.py file, two files, 2DFAN4-cd938726ad.zip and s3fd-619a316812.pth, are downloaded, but then the process crashes with an error:

(deep3d_pytorch) C:\temp\Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch>python face.py
Downloading: "https://www.adrianbulat.com/downloads/python-fan/s3fd-619a316812.pth" to C:\Users\ivanenkosy/.cache\torch\hub\checkpoints\s3fd-619a316812.pth
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 85.7M/85.7M [00:02<00:00, 34.4MB/s]
Downloading: "https://www.adrianbulat.com/downloads/python-fan/2DFAN4-cd938726ad.zip" to C:\Users\ivanenkosy/.cache\torch\hub\checkpoints\2DFAN4-cd938726ad.zip
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 91.9M/91.9M [00:03<00:00, 31.7MB/s]
0%|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "face.py", line 7, in 
preds = fa.get_landmarks_from_directory('my_set')
File "C:\Users\ivanenkosy\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\deep3d_pytorch\lib\site-packages\face_alignment\api.py", line 291, in get_landmarks_from_directory
for (image_path, image) in tqdm(dataloader, disable=not show_progress_bar):
File "C:\Users\ivanenkosy\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\deep3d_pytorch\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1133, in **iter**
for obj in iterable:
File "C:\Users\ivanenkosy\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\deep3d_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 628, in **next**
data = self._next_data()
File "C:\Users\ivanenkosy\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\deep3d_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1316, in _next_data
idx, data = self._get_data()
File "C:\Users\ivanenkosy\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\deep3d_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1282, in _get_data
success, data = self._try_get_data()
File "C:\Users\ivanenkosy\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\deep3d_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1133, in _try_get_data
raise RuntimeError('DataLoader worker (pid(s) {}) exited unexpectedly'.format(pids_str)) from e
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 14644, 14632) exited unexpectedly

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).